# AWS SDK for C++ sending templated email with SES

Tags: c++, amazon-ses

I am attempting to send a templated email through aws ses using their c++ sdk api. I have downloaded the latest sdk, but it only offers sesv2 and not ses. I can see the SESClient located in the aws-cpp-sdk-email directory, but don't know how to include it in the build.

My question is - How can I build the sdk to include access to the ses client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, unlike all of the other services, the ses service is located in the aws-cpp-sdk-email directory and not the aws-cpp-sdk-ses directory.

Also, to build the BUILD_ONLY variable must be set to "s3;email". Note that their are NO SPACES between the two services listed and that they must be separated with a semicolon.